# python how to form dict from this file

Tags: python

need small help. I have a large file which contains mainly lines from below screen shot. 
There is empty line(s) between each block that start with string 'zone'.

How can I form  dictionary  so that test_1, test_2 and test_3 are my keys and my values are all lines till empty line?

Example of first key

key = test_1

values = ['* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xxxx]','* fcid 0x170016 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:43] [xxxxxxxxx]']

Any good tip?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Here is the text:

```
zone name test_1 vsan xx

* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xxx]
* fcid 0x170016 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:43] [xxxxxx]

zone name test_2 vsan xx

* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xx]
* fcid 0x170017 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:63] [xxx]

zone name test_2 vsan yy

pwwn 10:00:00:90:fa:81:bb:f2
* fcid 0x0b00c0 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:07:e6:2e:26]
```

Comment: Include the file as text not as an image, makes it so much easier to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead assertion with a regular expression.

Try [`(?m)^zone\sname\s(\w+).*([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]+zone\sname\s|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/f9asoQ/2)

***In action***

```
import re

pattern = r'(?m)^zone\sname\s(\w+).*([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]+zone\sname\s|\Z)'

with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = {k: [
    i for i in v.split('\n') if i
    ] for k, v in dict(re.findall(pattern, f.read())).items()}

  print(data)
```

Result:

```
{'test_1': ['* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xxx]', '* fcid 0x170016 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:43] [xxxxxx]'], 'test_2': ['* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xx]', '* fcid 0x170017 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:63] [xxx]'], 'test_3': ['pwwn 10:00:00:90:fa:81:bb:f2', '* fcid 0x0b00c0 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:07:e6:2e:26]']}
```

Regex Explanation:

```
(?m)                             # asserts multiline matching
^zone\sname\s                    # matches zone name at start of line
(                                # matching group 1
  \w+                            # Matches your key
)                                
.*                               # Matches any character but new line
(                                # Matching group 2
  [\s\S]*?                       # Matches  until...
)
(?=                              # ... this group is found
  [\n\r]+
  zone\sname                     # same as first match
  \s
  |                              # or
  \Z                             # end of string
)
```

Comment: cheers Chrisz, will try this one although looks very complex to me :).

Comment: I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Wauu...nice and works.. need to do some more readings on re!!

Comment: Make sure you include my most recent update.  It properly formats the values into a list of lines

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot differs from text example: different newlines, and test_2 repeated. Thus, guessing your intent:

```
txt = """
zone name test_1 vsan xx
* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xxx]
* fcid 0x170016 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:43] [xxxxxx]

zone name test_2 vsan xx
* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xx]
* fcid 0x170017 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:63] [xxx]

zone name test_2 vsan yy
pwwn 10:00:00:90:fa:81:bb:f2
* fcid 0x0b00c0 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:07:e6:2e:26]
"""

result = dict()
for block in txt.split("\n\n"):
    lines = block.strip().split("\n")
    k = lines[0].split(" ")[2]
    result.update({k: list(filter(lambda l: l.startswith("*"), block.split("\n")))})

print(result)
```

And if the lines not starting with an asterisk should be included, then:

```
result = dict()
for block in txt.split("\n\n"):
    lines = block.strip().split("\n")
    k = lines[0].split(" ")[2]
    result.update({k: lines[1:]})
```

Comment: cheers Bartek, will test this one also. I can at least read (and understand) your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
import io

txt = """
zone name test_1 vsan xx

* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xxx]
* fcid 0x170016 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:43] [xxxxxx]

zone name test_2 vsan xx

* fcid 0x170024 [pwwn 10:00:00:00:c9:5f:84:93] [xx]
* fcid 0x170017 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:16:60:ef:63] [xxx]

zone name test_3 vsan yy

pwwn 10:00:00:90:fa:81:bb:f2
* fcid 0x0b00c0 [pwwn 50:06:0e:80:07:e6:2e:26]
"""

BLANK, KEY, DATA = 0, 1, 2

def decide_line(line):
    if (not line) or line.isspace():
        return BLANK
    else:
        return KEY if line.startswith('zone') else DATA

data_map = {}

with io.StringIO(txt) as f:
#with with open('file.txt') as f:
    key = None
    for data_type, lines in groupby(map(str.strip, f), decide_line):
        if data_type == KEY:
            key = next(lines).split()[2]
        elif data_type == DATA:
            data_map[key] = list(lines)
```